# Move all .jpeg from directory structure into one folder on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, file, osx-snow-leopard, directory, image

Recently my iPhoto database got all screwed up and I need to extract all of the originals from a folder structure to a central folder on the desktop.  Instead of going one by one through all of the folders, I would like to move all of them through a bash command or script.  Any suggestions.

I looked into rsync but I think that only takes the folders structure.

Answer (score 8):

```
find /path/to/original/folder -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec mv {} /path/to/new/folder \;
```

Comment: WARNING: if you have multiple photos with the same filename, this process will delete all but one of them (and I don't mean "put in the trash", I mean delete).  To avert this potential destruction, add the `-n` flag to the `mv` command (i.e. `... -exec mv -n {} ...`).  And making a backup first would be a really good idea...