# Can't move 100K jpgs from my root to another folder

Tags: bash, terminal

I accidentally saved 100K jpgs to my root folder, I'd like to move just the jpgs and not the other files like my applications folder to a new folder on my desktop. I tried:

```
home$ mv *.png ~/Desktop/images
```

But it returns:

```
-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See [Move all .jpeg from directory structure into one folder on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364579/move-all-jpeg-from-directory-structure-into-one-folder-on-mac-os-x) and add `-maxdepth 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the shell tries to pass all of the parameters to `mv`. Try

```
for filename in *.png
do
  mv "$filename" ~/Desktop/images/.
done
```

**edit: png, not jpg .,.,**

Comment: Thank you for this @Jens, nothing happens when I try this

Comment: My bad .... png, not jpg, updated

Comment: Still nothing, I waited 10 minutes, it just does nothing and the folder is still empty

Comment: Did you Try the version with *.png? PS: you Said you saved jpgs but your error indicates png files

Comment: There are both jpgs and pngs in there so it won't make a difference, maybe it's not working because there are so many files?

Comment: `ls *.png` is going to fail for the same reason `mv *.png ...` failed, ignoring the general problem of using the output of `ls` in a script.